# What is the correct "but is" or "but isn't" at the beginning of an interrogative sentence?

Tags: grammar

I read this sentences :

> I figured… together , we might just be untouchable.So far, we've been pretty good at our job.But is losing one of our own too high a price to pay?

and here is the last sentence I don't really understand is it correct ?

> but is losing one of our own *too high* a price to pay?

I can't understand why it's just *but*.I mean, I translate it directly.

> is that too much of a price?

I mean it's kind of lost to me **isn't it**.

That is, I would rewrite it like this:

> isn't that too expensive a price for us?

Or there is take my sentence, then so:

> but **isn't** losing one of our own *too high* a price to pay?

I hope I described the question correctly.That is, I wonder if it is correct that in my sentence it is just **but**? isn't it necessary to add **isn't** or but itself carries such a meaning?

I would be happy to help, thank you

Comment: Where did you read this? It looks to me as if the last two clauses should be all one sentence, separated by a comma - especially as you have not given the word _but_ a capital letter. _But_ introduces an idea different from the feeling expressed in the first half of the sentence.

Comment: @KateBunting I read it in a comics .it's separated by a dot there

Comment: I see you have edited the passage. There should also be a space after a full stop/period (so your last comment should read _I read it in a comic. It's separated..._

Comment: "Isn't it too high a price?" means that the speaker thinks that it _is_, and is asking for agreement. "Is it too high a price?" means that the speaker is suggesting that possibly it _could be_.